# Error in is_atomic(x) : object 'rlang_is_atomic' not found when using readxl

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to import my sample excel dataset `sample.xlsx` below into R.

```
OrderDate   Region  Rep Item    Units   UnitCost    Total
1/6/2016    East    Jones   Pencil  95  1.99    189.05
1/23/2016   Central Kivell  Binder  50  19.99   999.5
2/9/2016    Central Jardine Pencil  36  4.99    179.64
2/26/2016   Central Gill    Pen 27  19.99   539.73
3/15/2016   West    Sorvino Pencil  56  2.99    167.44
4/1/2016    East    Jones   Binder  60  4.99    299.4
```

When I use the code below as I usually do, I am getting an error.

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("~/sample.xlsx")
Error in is_atomic(x) : object 'rlang_is_atomic' not found
```

I even tried restarting R and reinstalling `rlang` and then restarting R and the computer but to no avail.

In addition, I tried saving `sample.xlsx` as `sample.csv` and then importing it using `library(readr)` and `read_csv`, without success either.

Please, help me understand what is wrong with my approach and how I can solve this problem.

Below is my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggpubr_0.1.6       magrittr_1.5       reshape2_1.4.3    
[4] readxl_1.0.0       brms_2.1.0         Rcpp_0.12.16      
[7] betareg_3.1-0      zoib_1.5.1         abind_1.4-5       
[10] Formula_1.2-2      matrixcalc_1.0-3   rjags_4-6         
[13] coda_0.19-1        stringr_1.3.0      dplyr_0.7.4       
[16] purrr_0.2.4        readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.8.0       
[19] tibble_1.4.2       ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 tidyverse_1.2.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] nlme_3.1-131.1       matrixStats_0.53.1  
[3] xts_0.10-2           lubridate_1.7.3     
[5] threejs_0.3.1        httr_1.3.1          
[7] rstan_2.17.3         tools_3.4.2         
[9] R6_2.2.2             DT_0.4              
[11] lazyeval_0.2.1       colorspace_1.3-2    
[13] nnet_7.3-12          withr_2.1.2         
[15] gridExtra_2.3        mnormt_1.5-5        
[17] Brobdingnag_1.2-5    compiler_3.4.2      
[19] cli_1.0.0            rvest_0.3.2         
[21] shinyjs_1.0          xml2_1.2.0          
[23] sandwich_2.4-0       colourpicker_1.0    
[25] scales_0.5.0.9000    dygraphs_1.1.1.4    
[27] lmtest_0.9-36        mvtnorm_1.0-7       
[29] psych_1.8.3.3        ggridges_0.5.0      
[31] digest_0.6.15        StanHeaders_2.17.2  
[33] foreign_0.8-69       base64enc_0.1-3     
[35] pkgconfig_2.0.1      htmltools_0.3.6     
[37] htmlwidgets_1.2.1    rlang_0.2.0.9001    
[39] rstudioapi_0.7       shiny_1.0.5         
[41] bindr_0.1.1          zoo_1.8-1           
[43] jsonlite_1.5         crosstalk_1.0.0     
[45] gtools_3.5.0         inline_0.3.14       
[47] modeltools_0.2-21    loo_1.1.0           
[49] bayesplot_1.5.0      Matrix_1.2-12       
[51] munsell_0.4.3        stringi_1.1.7       
[53] flexmix_2.3-14       plyr_1.8.4          
[55] grid_3.4.2           parallel_3.4.2      
[57] forcats_0.3.0        crayon_1.3.4        
[59] miniUI_0.1.1         lattice_0.20-35     
[61] haven_1.1.1          hms_0.4.2           
[63] pillar_1.2.1         igraph_1.2.1        
[65] markdown_0.8         shinystan_2.4.0     
[67] stats4_3.4.2         rstantools_1.4.0    
[69] glue_1.2.0           modelr_0.1.1        
[71] httpuv_1.3.6.2       cellranger_1.1.0    
[73] gtable_0.2.0         assertthat_0.2.0    
[75] mime_0.5             xtable_1.8-2        
[77] broom_0.4.3          rsconnect_0.8.8     
[79] shinythemes_1.1.1    bindrcpp_0.2.2      
[81] bridgesampling_0.4-0
```

Comment: Hi @Aurèle. Thanks but does not work. It says: `Error: 'OrderDate Region Rep Item Units UnitCost Total 1/6/2016 East Jones Pencil 95 1.99 189.05 1/23/2016 Central Kivell Binder 50 19.99 999.5 2/9/2016 Central Jardine Pencil 36 4.99 179.64 2/26/2016 Central Gill Pen 27 19.99 539.73 3/15/2016 West Sorvino Pencil 56 2.99 167.44 4/1/2016 East Jones Binder 60 4.99 299.4' does not exist in current working directory ('C:~/Documents')`

Comment: Sorry, I had problems with text formatting in comments. What about `readr::read_delim("OrderDate Region Rep Item Units UnitCost Total\n1/6/2016 East Jones Pencil 95 1.99 189.05\n1/23/2016 Central Kivell Binder 50 19.99 999.5\n2/9/2016 Central Jardine Pencil 36 4.99 179.64\n2/26/2016 Central Gill Pen 27 19.99 539.73\n3/15/2016 West Sorvino Pencil 56 2.99 167.44\n4/1/2016 East Jones Binder 60 4.99 299.4\n", delim = " ")` ?

Comment: Now it says: `Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_,  : 
  Evaluation error: object 'rlang_is_atomic' not found.`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using a development version of `rlang`? Otherwise can you reinstall it from CRAN? (I tried with the same dev version but couldn't reproduce, though it's still worth a try)

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved after uninstalling `rlang` and then installing its CRAN version. Please post this solution as an answer so that I can formally accept it and make it easier for other users to locate the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the development version of `rlang` was causing the issue (`rlang_0.2.0.9001`).

A solution is to `remove.packages("rlang")` and re-install from CRAN: `install.packages("rlang", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`.